# What happens at the input node in an inception module during the backwards pass?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network

Consider the following inception module, taken from [GoogLeNet](https://storage.googleapis.com/pub-tools-public-publication-data/pdf/43022.pdf).

[image: Inception Block]

Here, concatenate encodes *depth* concatenation. Now, upon receiving the gradient corresponding to the concatenation node in the given diagram, we partition the matrix representing said gradient up into separate matrices the same in which we concatenated corresponding matrices during the forward pass. From here, we perform the backward pass along each of the four routes. My question is then, once these four gradients reach the $A^{[l-1]\{t\}}$ node, do we sum them together?

In general, when multiple gradients are propagated backward into the same node, we add the gradients together and complete our backward pass with the resulting gradient, so it seems natural to conclude that we would do the same in this case, but since this is my first time seeing the concatenation operation in a computation graph, I figured it's better to clarify.

Thank you, in advance, for any feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you sum. One way to convince yourself is to remember that the behavior of calculating the backward pass is independent at each node, because of the chain rule, so it doesn't even matter that there's a concatenation later on—whenever you split up the nodes the way you do here, the gradients add.